# How to include multiple Views in an already existing feature?

Tags: views, 7, features

I have to work with an old Drupal 7 site. It's using features. I created some new views, now I have to include these 2 new views into a feature which already has 1 view. How can I do it and which steps or hooks I should follow? Thank you

Comment: If you mean Features module, you can do it through the admin interface (admin>structure>features).

Answer (score 1):

Feature module provides admin interface for each feature you create.

1. Just go to this page: admin>structure>feature
2. Find your feature
3. Edit it and check which Views to add.
4. Rebuild your custom feature module which your edited.
5. Open the code, delete old custom_feature module and add new custom_feature module which you just created.

You are done!